# My Xcode 7.2 Version is not installing

Tags: xcode

I am trying to download the Xcode 7.2.1 Version, but it just keeps saying installing on my computer, and nothing is happening. What do I do?

Comment: The Xcode installation in the Mac App Store is a bit broken, and often not very informative of what is going on. It also takes quite a while both to download and to install. Just be (very) patient.

Comment: It's more than a bit broken. I have one pane that says it was installed today, but there was still an "Update" button, so I'm installing again. I'm now 5 hours into the install and it's still stuck at 7 minutes remaining and no progress.

Comment: What program installs/downloads Xcode? Have you tried making a new user account to see if it's simply a user preference or file corruption issue?

Answer (score 2):

7.2 requires El Captain if I'm right, so make sure you're on El Captain on your Mac otherwise it won't install